# How to load/view structure of pickled object in Ipython console ? (Windows 7, Spyder, Ipython console)

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, pickle, spyder

I am learning the program written by other programmer. So I would like to view the structure of the pickled item.
   Since I need to know the structure of pickled data, I am trying to load pickle in Ipython using Spyder... e.g.:

```
import pickle

data1 = {'a': [1, 2.0, 3, 4+6j],
         'b': ('string', u'Unicode string'),
         'c': None}

selfref_list = [1, 2, 3]
#selfref_list.append(selfref_list)

output = open('data.pkl', 'wb')

# Pickle dictionary using protocol 0.
pickle.dump(data1, output)

# Pickle the list using the highest protocol available.
pickle.dump(selfref_list, output, -1)

output.close()
```

I would like to know the structure of the .pkl file pickled here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by `structure`.  If I run your code, I can then do:

```
In [6]: with open('data.pkl','rb') as f:
   ...:     x = pickle.load(f)
   ...:     y = pickle.load(f)
   ...:     
   ...:     
In [7]: x
Out[7]: {'a': [1, 2.0, 3, (4+6j)], 'b': ('string', 'Unicode string'), 'c': None}
In [8]: y
Out[8]: [1, 2, 3]
```

I can recover your successive writes with an equal number of reads.  If I try to get more I get a `EOFError: Ran out of input`.

What do you want to know?  How any objects there are on the file?  The structure of each object?  The conversion between Python object and bytes on the file?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I wanted to retrieve the pickled data in the console.   

I would like to know if I could know what type of data the pickled object contains without loading 
For eg:
type(x) is dict
type(y): list

Comment: Because 
we can give 2 times to load pickle when we know only 2 items are pickled
x = pickle.load(f)
y = pickle.load(f)
but when we don't know how many items are there...Then how to deal with such issues.

Answer (score 1):

What to do when we don't know how many items are pickled...

Found an answer:

```
unpickled_store = []
file_id = open('data.pkl','rb')
while True:
        try:
            unpickled_item = pickle.load(file_id)
            unpickled_store.append(unpickled_item)
        except EOFError:
            break
```